# Readonly/Disabled input not submitting in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I've been having problems creating a form in Angular 2. I need to submit some values that are dinamically generated by a service. 
Using the http module of Angular I get a price and then the user can now exactly how much bitcoin is an X amount of chilean pesos. What I'm trying to do is submit all that data. I can't do it because angular forms are not submitting the disabled/readonly inputs. These inputs are the exchange rate and the target amount (equivalent in btc).

I tried the template driven approach and the data driven approach with no success. I can't even log the values in the console. If I remove disabled or readonly property from the inputs the values are logged in the console and submitted to my database.

Thanks for taking the time to help me. This is my code:

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SurbtcService } from '../services/exchange/surbtc.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { FiredbService } from '../services/firedb.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
})
export class DashboardComponent {

  //myForm2: FormGroup;
  //error = false;
  //errorMessage = '';

  constructor(private surbtcService: SurbtcService, private fb: FormBuilder, private dbfr: FiredbService) {
/*
          this.myForm2 = this.fb.group({
            email: ['', Validators.email],
      clpmount: ['', Validators.required],
      btcmount: [''],
      rate: [''],
      descripcion: ['']

        });
 */  }
//Form

info = {
  rate: '',
  btcmount: ''
};


onSub() {
 console.log(this.info);
  }



  //surbtcservice

  prices: any;
  baseAmount: 1;

  get exchangeRate() {
   return this.prices * 0.989
    }

  get targetAmount() {
   return this.baseAmount / this.exchangeRate;
    }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.surbtcService.getPrices()
      .subscribe(prices => {
       this.prices = prices.ticker.min_ask[0];
       console.log(prices.ticker.min_ask[0]);
        });
    } }
```

As you can see in my code, the data driven approach is commented except for the function used to submit the form.

html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSub(f)" #f="ngForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <md-input-container class="full-width">
              <input mdInput type="number" id="montoclp" name="clpmount" placeholder="Ingrese el monto en CLP" [(ngModel)]="baseAmount" name="clp">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="full-width">
              <input mdInput class="form-control" name="btcmount" [ngModel]="info.btcmount" placeholder="Monto en BTC" id="vat" [value]="targetAmount | number:'1.8-8'" readonly>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="full-width">
              <input mdInput class="form-control" name="rate" [ngModel]="info.rate" placeholder="Tasa de cambio" id="street" [value]="exchangeRate | number:'1.0-0'" readonly>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="full-width">
              <input mdInput type="mail" class="form-control" ngModel name="email" placeholder="E-mail cliente (Opcional)">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="full-width">
              <input mdInput type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción pago (Opciona)">
            </md-input-container>
          </div>
          <button md-raised-button type="submit" color="primary" class="btn-w-md">Confirmar</button><div class="divider divider-sm"></div>
        </form>
```

Thanks again!

EDIT!!!:

data driven html:

```
            <form [formGroup]="myForm2" (ngSubmit)="onSub()">
              <div class="form-group">
                <md-input-container class="full-width">
                  <input mdInput type="number" id="montoclp" name="clpmount" placeholder="Ingrese el monto en CLP" formControlName="clpmount" [(ngModel)]="baseAmount">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="full-width">
                  <input mdInput class="form-control" name="btcmount" placeholder="Monto en BTC" formControlName="btcmount" [value]="targetAmount | number:'1.8-8'">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="full-width">
                  <input mdInput class="form-control" name="rate" formControlName="rate" placeholder="Tasa de cambio" [value]="exchangeRate | number:'1.0-0'">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="full-width">
                  <input mdInput type="mail" class="form-control" formControlName="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail cliente (Opcional)">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="full-width">
                  <input mdInput type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="descripcion" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción pago (Opciona)">
                </md-input-container>
              </div>
              <button md-raised-button type="submit" color="primary" class="btn-w-md">Confirmar</button><div class="divider divider-sm"></div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Will you please post proper code ? it not looks good or updated . because onSub() you are passing form but there is no parameter for this in that function

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use **[`getRawValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue)**, which gives you all form values, even the disabled ones.

So when your form looks something like this:

```
this.myForm2 = this.fb.group({
  email: ['', Validators.email],
  clpmount: ['', Validators.required],
  btcmount: [{value: '', disabled: true}],
  ....
});
```

using

```
this.myForm2.getRawValue()
```

will include in above example `btcmount` value.

**EDIT:**

Seeing the template... In reactive forms, Angular disregards `value` and `[value]`. We can overcome this and use one-way binding, which I also suggest you do with your field `clpAmount` and set `[ngModel]="baseAmount"`. Why? Well, first of all the `ngModel` directive isn't even included in `ReactiveFormsModule`, so from that, even not clearly mentioned in docs, we can all but assume they should not be used together. We can also understand it, if using `[(ngModel)]` together, we would have two bidirectional bindings, which can sometimes cause issues.

`[ngModel]` is better, since Angular just binds the value from TS to template, and doesn't really care what happens next. In some cases, `[ngModel]` can be useful in reactive forms, this is one of those cases. Even though reactive forms ignore `value`, it does not ignore `ngModel`, so we can use that just fine here! So exchange `[value]` with `[ngModel]`:

```
<input mdInput  formControlName="btcmount" [ngModel]="targetAmount | number:'1.8-8'">

<input mdInput formControlName="rate" placeholder="Tasa de cambio" [ngModel]="exchangeRate | number:'1.0-0'">
```

Now you have all values when you use `getRawValue()` :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer AJT_82, but its not working. Still the same thing. When I submit the conform I'm console logging `this.myForm2.getRawValue()` but I only get the inputs that are not disabled: `Object {email: "cmarg@dss.com", clpmount: 2000, btcmount: "", rate: "", descripcion: "dsadadas"}`

Comment: That look like all values to me... according to your code you have 5 fields?

Comment: Yes, but nor btcmount nor rate are empty. Here, look at this screenshot: https://ibb.co/fFwtc5

Comment: image does not show. Well, when you used reactive form, did you set the values to form controls?

Comment: You are only showing the template driven form in your question, could you show us the attempt of reactive form please?

Comment: You are a genius! It worked! I learned a lot with your answer, thank you man!

Comment: Haha :D Glad to hear it was helpful, so you are very welcome. Have a good day and haaaaappy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

**If you want all the form values then**

Change this function

```
onSub() {
 console.log(this.info);
}
```

With

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

onSub(formData : NgForm) {
 console.log(formData.value);
}
```

> **Readonly/Disabled input not submitting in Angular**
>
> **Disabled** will never be submitted in any form 
>   But **Readonly** , you will always get that in submitted form ,
>
> Issue is with your code not with the angular

Comment: Sorry for not posting that, you were right, I missed to post the parameter because I did a lot of refactoring and got kind of confused, but I already done what you said and I did again in case I made an error, but its definitly not submitting the disabled/readonly values. Here is a screenshot of my html and console https://ibb.co/fFwtc5. Its almost the same with data driven approach

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Vivek's ansver, with a reactive form, you would do it like this:

```
this.myForm2 = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.email],
      clpmount: ['', Validators.required],
      btcmount: [''],
      rate: [''],
      descripcion: ['']

});
```

and

```
public onSub() {
  console.log(this.myForm2.value);
}
```

or (on changes):

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}
```

basically you want to grab the data from the actual form, and not from your model. Same thing goes for model driven, as Vivek outlined (pass in the form instead of using the model)